# Question of 'Ruby on Rails3 Tutorial Live Lesson #5 by Michael Hartl

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I use spec to write integration test, such as should have a Home page at '/', I always get failed, I don't know if this is something with my Rails version which is 3.0.0.9.

The output is like follow, someone please help me out.

1) LayoutLinks should have a Home page at '/'
    Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
    **stack level too deep**
    # /Users/xiongzhend/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/forwardable.rb:185

2) LayoutLinks should have a Contact page at '/contact'
    Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
    **stack level too deep**
    # /Users/xiongzhend/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/forwardable.rb:185

3) LayoutLinks should have an About page at '/about'
    Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
    **stack level too deep**
    # /Users/xiongzhend/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/forwardable.rb:185

4) LayoutLinks should have a Help page at '/help'
    Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
    **stack level too deep**
    # /Users/xiongzhend/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/forwardable.rb:185

5) LayoutLinks should have a signup page at '/signup'
    Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
    **stack level too deep**
    # /Users/xiongzhend/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/forwardable.rb:185

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue caused by Webrat when using RSpec 2.0.0beta18.

There are 2 ways to fix the problem:

1. Downgrade Webrat to version 0.7.1 by editing your `Gemfile` within the `sample_app` directory with the following:

   ```
   group :development do
   gem 'rspec-rails', '2.0.0.beta.18'
   gem 'webrat', '0.7.1'
   end

   group :test do
   gem 'rspec', '2.0.0.beta.18'
   gem 'webrat', '0.7.1'
   end
   ```

   Then go into your favorite terminal and type the following command `bundle update webrat`.
2. The alternative method is to simply use the new version of rspec which has apparently fixed the problem. Edit your Gemfile with the following code:

   ```
   group :development do
   gem 'rspec-rails'
   end

   group :test do
   gem 'rspec'
   end
   ```

   Which will install the latest version of R-Spec from `rubygems.org` (currently 2.6.0).